# How to create database from *.datasource.ts?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback4

As mentioned [in the docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/PostgreSQL-connector.html#defining-models). I can [generate database objects](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Database-migrations.html#auto-update-the-database-explicitly) depending on `*.model.ts` content using `npm run migrate`.

How can I create a new database if it doesn't exist at data source level (`*.datasource.ts`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately LoopBack doesn't support this kind of feature as some of the community moderators [answered me](https://loopbackio.slack.com/archives/C01177XQN8N/p1610959014042300?thread_ts=1610877905.034900&cid=C01177XQN8N) in LB Slack c